# Button that becomes a form and then returns to button on submit

Tags: reactjs

Just starting out programming in React and I want a button that transforms into a form when clicked and then back to a button on submit.
The form won't go back to being a button though, otherwise it works fine locally, but I cant get it to work at all on jsfiddle.

Here's my fiddle:

```
var nameList = [];

var ClickMe = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            text: "Add name"
        };
    },

    handleClick: function() {
        if (this.state.text == "Add Name") {
            this.setState({
                text: "Save"
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                text: "Add Name"
            });
        }
    },

    handleChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        });
    },

    handleSubmit(event) {
        nameList.push(this.state.value);
        console.log(nameList);
        this.setState({
            text: "Add Name"
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    },

    render: function() {
        if (this.state.text == "Add Name") {
            return ( <
                form onSubmit = {
                    this.handleSubmit
                } >
                <
                label >
                Name:
                <
                input type = "text"
                value = {
                    this.state.value
                }
                onChange = {
                    this.handleChange
                }
                /> <
                /label> <
                input type = "submit"
                value = "Submit" / >
                <
                /form>
            )
        } else {
            return ( <
                button onClick = {
                    this.handleClick
                }
                type = "button" > {
                    this.state.text
                } <
                /button>
            )
        }
    }
});

ReactDOM.render( <
    ClickMe / > ,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/petterwr/11vwamuz/1/

Comment: the first variable is supposed to be part of the code, but cant get it formatted that way, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you were trying to import an insecure script (http) over a secure jsfiddle url (https).
Anyways, I transferred your code to a different jsfiddle which has a better integration with React: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/92020/)

I changed a few things, as the fiddle required, I used a class instead createClass, which means I had to use a constructor. Also I changed the event handlers to arrow notation so when you try to access `this.state`, `this` will point to the class instance itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for the tip regardeing insecure script over a secure fiddle! I really want to use createClass though and it seems to be possible - here is a random example: https://jsfiddle.net/guillaumemaka/20mbecfu/

Comment: Cool, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that are wrong with your logic. Initially you set text to "Add name", so the button is rendered (since it doesn't equal "Add Name"). Then you set the text to "Add Name" once the form is submitted, so it re-renders the form rather than reverting back to the button. I took your example and changed the way you handle the state:

```
var nameList = [];
var ClickMe = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return { 
            enterName: false
        };
    },

    handleClick: function() {
        this.setState({
            enterName: true
        });
    },

    handleChange: function(event){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    },

    handleSubmit(event) {
        nameList.push(this.state.value);
        console.log(nameList);
        this.setState({
            enterName: false
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    },

    render: function() {
        if(this.state.enterName){
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                      Name:
                      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                  </form>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <button onClick={this.handleClick} type="button">
                    Add Name
                </button>
            )
        }           
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ClickMe />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

You can always use text rather than `true` or `false` if you need it for your component.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats a lot clearer than my code, just a small typo there React.render in last statement should be ReactDOM.render.